# How to send AJAX calls using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I use Jquery and ajax to post the content of a form to a php page for calculations/sql statements etc and display the response back to the page?

```
<form name="cancelForm" action="orderCanceled.php" method="POST">
    <input name="cancelExcursion" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['orderNo'] ?>" />
    <input name="qty" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'] ?>" />
    <input name="excursionId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['excursionId'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel Booking" id="blueButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: have you looked here? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: what have try with ajax please share it

Comment: @garry does the below make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do something like the below.

Firstly, you create a `data` object that you will post to your php endpoint. This data object is a holder which is populated with all values from the form. The way the values get added to the object from the form is that you loop over the form and add each value from the form to the `data` object.

```
var data = {};
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    data[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

The next step is to set up the `ajax` `POST` request that will send the data to the server. It is here that the previous defined `data` object gets posted.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "orderCanceled.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
     //response will contain the data returned 
     //from orderCanceled.php
     $("body").append(response)       
  }
})
.done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
});
```

In the success callback you will receive the response from the orderCanceled.php. You can manipulate this response and display what you choose to show on the page by using javascript's dot notation on the response object returned.

So for example if the response object is a json object and looked like this:

```
{
   "username": "garry",  
   "site": "StackOverflow"
}
```

You can then get the value of `username` by using `response.username`. This will return `"garry"`, and same for `response.site` This will return `"StackOverflow"`.

[You should read about accessing object properties on the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). If you are dealing with ajax requests it is necessary that you understand this to deal with sort of `json` response from a server. You can either use dot notation or bracket notation. Both are demonstrated below, and will return the. It is up to you which one you use, there will not be any difference in result.

So back to the above section in the `POST` request, if the json object above was returned you would do this:

```
success: function(response) {
    //data will contain the data returned 
    //from orderCanceled.php
     $("body").append(response.username);  
     $("body").append(response["site"]);     
}
```

Comment: thanks, so this method puts the data accross to orderCanceled.php, how can i get the results from said page to appear back in a specified div on the original page?

Comment: can you elaborate by what you mean by the `said page`? do you mean how do u display what the php script returns?

Comment: the results from orderCanceled.php. so yes how to display what the php script returns

Answer (score 0):

You could submit a form like this..

```
var cancelExcursion=$("input[name=cancelExcursion]").val();
var qty=$("input[name=qty]").val();
var excursionId=$("input[name=excursionId]").val();
var url='orderCanceled.php';
var data="cancelExcursion="+cancelExcursion+"&qty="+qty+"&excursionId"+excursionId;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
       // You can set a loading image/div when form is submitting
    },
    success: function(response) {
// response contains the result from  orderCanceled.php
        // code for success notification
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
        // code for showing error
    }
});
```